# How to unlock inventory slots?

Tags: how-to-survive

In How to Survive you have a number of locked inventory slots, but at least so far (58% complete, playing as Jack) I have not found a way to open up any of these slots.

I thought that the bag I made for the monkey quest may have been the key, but I don't remember it being usable.

Is there a way to unlock the extra slots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually almost had it. You can create bags with animal skin and thread. I believe there is a max of 2 bags which kinda sucks because there isn't any where you can store your spare junk other than carrying it around.